# Determine form of cubic polynomial given initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, cubics

If I am given a function $P = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ and following:

$P(0) = P_1$,

$P(1) = P_2$,

$P^\prime(0) = v_0$,

$P^\prime(1) = v_1$.

How would I solve for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$?

**Edit:**

I have tried following:

$P(0) = P_1$ => d = P1

$P^\prime(0) = v_1$ => c = v1

However, I am not sure how would I solve for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Hint: form a system of equations.

Comment: I am a total noob in maths. I am watching videos on Hermite splines and it just skips these steps. I know what system of equations are, but again, I have no idea how to do that.  I would really appreciate if you guys could help.

Comment: I corrected you LaTeX equations.  Please update the question with your attempt at the solution so we can help you.  Otherwise, the question will likely be closed.

Comment: If you guys cannot answer, maybe you can suggest me what should I learn to solve this equation?

Comment: All I needed was something like this:
https://yutsumura.com/find-a-polynomial-satisfying-the-given-conditions/

I know that lots of people post useless questions on this website, however, you guys have to remember that not everyone knows math like you do. :)

Comment: @BunnyDhaliwal You wrote the equations for $P(0), P'(0)$ and got $c,d$ which are correct. Write the equations for $P(1), P'(1)$ and see what you get from those.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, $P'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$.

From condition 1, that $P(0)=P_1$, we learn that $d=P_1$.

From condition 2, that $P(1)=P_2$, we learn that $a+b+c+d=P_2=a+b+c+P_1$.

From condition 3, that $P′(0)=v_0$, we learn that $c=v_0$.

From condition 4, that $P′(1)=v_1$, we learn that $3a+2b+c=v_1=3a+2b+v_0$.

Thus, we can express

$a=P_2-(b+c+d)$.

$a=P_2-(b+c+P_1)$.

$a=\frac{v_1-v_0-2b}{3}$.

$a=\frac{v_1-c-2b}{3}$.

$b=P_2-(a+c+d)$.

$b=P_2-(a+c+P_1)$.

$b=\frac{v_1-v_0-3a}{2}$.

$b=\frac{v_1-c-3a}{2}$.

$c=v_0$.

$d=P_1$.